# Distribute APK on webserver

Tags: php, android, installation, download, apk

I've created an app and want users to be able to download and install the app from my website on their device (phone).
I used Android Studio and generated a signed APK. Now i have 2 files (app-release.apk and output.json)

I've tried some codes but most of them I got "HTTP ERROR 500" and then I tried this simple code (PHP):

```
$file_name  = "app-release.apk";
$file_ext   = "apk";
$file_path  = 'my/app/folder/' . $file_name;
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-description: File Transfer");
$contenttype = "application/com.android.package-install";
header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_path."\""); 
header("Content-Tranfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file_path);
```

With this I can download the APK on the device.
But...

1. I cannot install the app. It just say "cannot open".
2. The APK name change to this in the device download folder --> my_app_folder_app-release.apk
   And I don't want the users to see the website structure/folders.

Oke my questions are.
How can I let the user to download and install APK from the webserver /website properly.
And how can I prevent that the APK name changes?

For the first problem ... "I cannot install the app" ... I cannot install the app from the browser downloads. I have to install the app from the File Manager. This is because I changed the security so I can install unknown apps from the File Manager.
So this is solved

Comment: You can do all with the right code.

Comment: For the first problem ... "I cannot install the app" ... I cannot install the app from the browser downloads. I have to install the app from the File Manager. This is because I changed the security so I can install unknown apps from the File Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filename` after `Content-Disposition: attachment;` is expecting the NAME of the file that you want the file to be named when it is saved not the path to the existing file.

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$file_name"');`

Also if you wanted to serve APK directly from your server via a link, I suspect you you will need to add this line to your `.htaccess` on apache since APK isn't a default mime. After that you can link directly to the file and allow them to download it with no additional programming.

`AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive apk`